# Don't hide tooltip mouse pointer is on tooltip

Tags: jquery, html, tooltip

I have a tooltip code  in my program with jquery

```
  $(function() {
  var tooltips = $( ".g-link" ).tooltip();
  });

 <a href="#" class="g-link" title="Google">test</a>
```

Now it showing the tooltip,But i need to show the tooltip,when mouse pointer is on tooltip showed.now it is hide when the pointer outside the link.is there any options?
I tried with

```
    hide: {  duration: 5000 }
```

But it is hideing after the duration

Answer (score 1):

You can not achieve this functionality without modifying JQueryUI tooltip widget source.

You should check [Bootstrap Popover component](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) there is implementation of your case in this  [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2LRYT/)

```
<a href="#"  id="tooltip" data-toggle = "popover">Test</a>

 $(function() {
    var a = $('#tooltip');
    $( '#tooltip' ).popover({
        html:true,
        placement:"bottom",
        trigger:"hover",
        container: a,        
        content:'Content of popover',
        delay: { show: 150, hide: 150 }
    });   
 });
```